# Does not implement interface member iterator.next - Xamarin.Android java binding

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
Java_Libraries/obj/Debug/generated/src/Com.xxxxx.Transmitter.Ble.Internal.Profile.BackfillStreamElement.cs(82,82): Error CS0738: 'BackfillStreamElement.BackfillStreamElementIterator' does not implement interface member 'IIterator.Next()'. 'BackfillStreamElement.BackfillStreamElementIterator.Next()' cannot implement 'IIterator.Next()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Object'. (CS0738) (Android_xxxxx_Java_Libraries)
```

Please help me, how to solve this issue.

Java.Util.IIterator

Java.Lang.Object

I have tried below in Metadata.xml but no use:

```
<attr
    path="/api/package[@name='com.xxxx.transmitter.ble.internal.profile']/class[@name='BackfillStreamElement.BackfillStreamElementIterator']/method[@name='Next' and count(parameter)=0]"
    name="managedReturn">Java.Util.IIterator
</attr>
     <attr
    path="/api/package[@name='com.xxxx.transmitter.ble.internal.profile']/class[@name='BackfillStreamElement.BackfillStreamElementIterator.Next']/method[@name='iterator' and count(parameter)=0]"
    name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object
</attr>
```

Comment: Did you change the iterator to return type 'Object' like it is complaining about?

Comment: How can i do that? using metadata i edited the code as mentioned above. What can i do now?

Comment: Try to change return type of the method to match that of the interface member. Make the change with your `IIterator.Next()`. Check the error details in the below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0738

Comment: I changed the code, it's working now. But I get one error and I added Desugar.jar file and it's showing error Java exited with Code 1 and when I remove that file I'm getting error called NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Normally, we try to delete the bin and obj folder to clan and rebuild. Does this error occure all the times?